# Partitioned tables: Should we specify partition to select from, when writing sql queries on Partitioned Tables, or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if we partition a table in MSSQL, do we gain any performance from it - just by partition the table without rewriting the SQL-query, or is it necassery to also specify which partition to select from, to gain any extra performance from partition tables?

**Followup question if MSSQL does find the correct partition automatically**; 
Is it then any performance differences if we specify partition in the sql query or is the performance more or less the same when not specifying the partition?

Comment: The usual answer with performance questions: it depends. Yes, the optimizer applies partition elimination, meaning it's supposed to automatically exclude partitions based on the query. No, this doesn't always work flawlessly and there are various ways to massage the query to ensure this does happen. There is no feature for explicitly querying only a particular partition of a table, though. [See also](https://littlekendra.com/2015/11/17/did-my-query-eliminate-table-partitions-sql-server/).

Comment: For explicitly querying only a particular partition of a table see: $PARTITION https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I completely forgot about `$PARTITION`. :-P The reason I forgot is due to the drawbacks: you need to explicitly specify the partition function and you need to be aware of what the partitioning key is (introducing a dependency where none existed before). But it is a valid  way to select partitions directly -- just don't habitually add it to every query as a way to speed things up, since that just makes it harder to change things in the future.

Comment: its by $PARTITION i was thinking yes. 

My idea if its any point in "helping" MSSQL with finding correct partition is to create a function that finds a list of Ids that input parameter matches in the select query.

However, its quite a huge job to implement this kind of logic in hundred of sql queries so I want to know if its any point in doing it before starting to design a implementation to do this.